# How to push the for all i to the end of the equation in align?

Tags: align

I have a an equation like this which is valid for all i from 1 to k. How do I make the expression `i=1,...k` towards the end of the line without disturbing the existing alignment of `I_i = O_i`?

```
\begin{align}
    I_i = O_i,  i = 1,...k
\end{align}
```

Comment: What is aligned? You have no ampersand, and a single line.

Answer (score 2):

Please always provide MWE, which reproduce your problem.

Based on guessing ...

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{align}
    I_i & = O_i,  && i = 1,...k
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could use `\hskip x\linewidth` or `\hspace{x\linewidth}`, vary the x to the desired space/location. I presume that you use documentclass (article.cls) and amsmath.sty package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
\hspace{0.25\linewidth}   I_i = O_i, \hspace{0.25\linewidth} \forall\ i = 1,...k
\end{align}
\end{document}
```